# How can i publish my ios application without app store?

Tags: ios, server, app-store, host

I need to publish my ios application in my own server or host without using app store. is that possible?
If is it, how can i?
Note: i have an developer account from apple with a business program enrollment.

Comment: Enterprise or B2B.

Comment: What are your target users?  Employees? Testers? The general public?

Comment: Or ad hoc distribution of course.

Comment: Ad hoc distribution limits you to 100 devices, though.

Comment: Not sure whether this still works, but in the past it was possible to submit an App into the store and never actually release it. Promo codes worked as soon  as the App was in state "Pending Developer Release"...

Comment: @matt Enterprise

Comment: @Paulw11 No just my employees are target

Comment: Then you can use an Enterprise program or a B2B app and distribute via MDM.

Comment: @benjarwar thats ok if i can install app directly from my server or host. is it?

Comment: @Paulw11 This method is very difficult and involves a long process to submit and verify the application. I'm looking for a way to install software directly, without waiting for different Apple gadgets.

Comment: Enterprise program is the fastest. You can sign the app yourself and then distribute it yourself. You can use a web server, Apple Configurator or (recommended) MDM. There is no Apple review with the enterprise program

Comment: @Paulw11 oookey thats whats i need. thank you so much paulw11